# I am trying to run eclipse kura emulator and facing certain error can you help fix the problem?

Tags: eclipse, jetty, osgi-bundle, equinox, kura

I have install eclipse for committer with the help of archive Kura workspace. I am trying to run a Kura emulator for my university project. Before that, I even tried to install through eclipse advance installer but still facing many problems thereafter I got help from my friend which is working on his laptop however with the same method I am facing an error. After the workspace and set the target platform. I tried to run the configuration OSGi emulator OSX and facing the error given below.

```
2020-11-09T23:02:47,623 [Start Level: Equinox Container: 70a2bae5-4f78-4fac-b44c-769902787e41] INFO o.a.c.i.o.Activator - Camel activator starting
2020-11-09T23:02:47,640 [Start Level: Equinox Container: 70a2bae5-4f78-4fac-b44c-769902787e41] INFO o.a.c.i.o.Activator - Camel activator started
osgi> 2020-11-09T23:02:48,686 [Start Level: Equinox Container: 70a2bae5-4f78-4fac-b44c-769902787e41] INFO o.e.j.u.log - Logging initialized @2936ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
!SESSION 2020-11-09 23:02:46.069 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_102
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments: -dev file:/Users/sanif/kura/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Kura_Emulator_OSX/dev.properties -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:48.950
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:800)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:933)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1614)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: default : Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager.updated(HttpServerManager.java:92)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:62)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:308)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager.updated(HttpServerManager.java:90)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
... 19 more
Root exception:
org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: default : Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager.updated(HttpServerManager.java:92)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:62)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:933)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1614)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:308)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager.updated(HttpServerManager.java:90)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
... 19 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:48.978
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found; Component will fail

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.003
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.005
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] activate method [activate] not found; Component will fail

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.006
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found; Component will fail

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.006
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.082
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.083
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.108
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.109
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.143
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.144
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.151
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.151
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.178
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.179
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.184
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.185
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.186
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.211
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.358
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Exception in org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService()
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.factoryGetService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:222)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.getService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:111)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceConsumer$2.getService(ServiceConsumer.java:45)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:508)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:624)
at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ResourceTracker.addingService(ResourceTracker.java:39)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)
at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.openAllServiceTracker(Activator.java:91)
at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:55)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:933)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1614)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/kura/emulator/Emulator has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:655)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:578)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:446)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:564)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.initDependencyManagers(AbstractComponentManager.java:976)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.collectDependencies(AbstractComponentManager.java:1003)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:859)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:823)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse$1.run(ServiceFactoryUse.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.factoryGetService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:210)
... 30 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.486
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.490
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.492
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.498
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.513
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.519
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.521
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.522
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.524
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.525
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.528
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.530
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.536
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.537
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.541
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] bind method [setEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.542
!MESSAGE [org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService(30)] unbind method [unsetEmulator] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-11-09 23:02:49.577
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.4.0.v20170503-2025 [92] is not active.
```

Comment: The `UnsupportedClassVersionError` error is saying Kura requires Java 14 and you are only running Java 8

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that port 8080 is already in use on your system:

```
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
...
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Kura uses this port for the web UI. Either you already have another instance of Kura running or some other service is using port 8080 on your system.